# How to set display refresh rate to 120Hz via HDMI?

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, resolution

I have a display that supports 280 Hz and although I'm limited to an old Intel HD610 via HDMI, **on Windows I'm able to set the refresh rate up to 120 Hz** (checked on display menu), but on Linux I can only go to 99 Hz maximum.

What I'm doing:

```
cvt 1920 1080 120
```

Which prints:

```
# 1920x1080 119.93 Hz (CVT) hsync: 139.12 kHz; pclk: 369.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_120.00"  369.50  1920 2080 2288 2656  1080 1083 1088 1160 -hsync +vsync
```

Then:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_120.00"  369.50  1920 2080 2288 2656  1080 1083 1088 1160 -hsync +vsync
```

And:

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920x1080_120.00
```

Finally, when I try to set this custom refresh rate (via Xfce Display app), nothing happens; it goes back to the previous refresh rate. I did the same process with 90 Hz and it worked, but that's the maximum I could go.

My xorg (v1.20.10) log contains this interesting information:

```
                  intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20190822
[     3.606] (II) intel(0): Supported standard timings:
[     3.606] (II) intel(0): #0: hsize: 1280  vsize 720  refresh: 60  vid: 49281
[     3.606] (II) intel(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 720  refresh: 75  vid: 53121
[     3.606] (II) intel(0): #2: hsize: 1280  vsize 800  refresh: 60  vid: 129
[     3.606] (II) intel(0): #3: hsize: 1280  vsize 800  refresh: 75  vid: 3969
[     3.606] (II) intel(0): #4: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 60  vid: 49361
[     3.606] (II) intel(0): #5: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 85  vid: 55761
[     3.606] (II) intel(0): #6: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 100  vid: 59601
[     3.606] (II) intel(0): #7: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 120  vid: 64721
```